# How do I add appropriate constraints in GUI to make layout look like it does in design view?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am struggling with how to use the GUI to make a constraint layout.  I have watched and done tutorials, but applying them I am stuck.  Any suggestions how to make my screen shot look as it is with constraints?
[image]

Here is what I have so far implemented via GUI:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.udacity.sandwichclub.DetailActivity">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_iv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/sandwich_picture_content_description"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/description_tv"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.031" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/origin_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/detail_error_message"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/origin_label_tv"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/origin_label_tv"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:labelFor="@id/origin_tv"
    android:text="@string/detail_place_of_origin_label"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="304dp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/also_known_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/detail_error_message"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/also_knwon_label_tv"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/also_knwon_label_tv"
    android:layout_width="91dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:labelFor="@id/also_known_tv"
    android:text="@string/detail_also_known_as_label"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="414dp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ingredients_tv"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:text="@string/detail_error_message"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="545dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/detail_ingredients_label_tv"
    android:layout_width="84dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:labelFor="@id/ingredients_tv"
    android:text="@string/detail_ingredients_label"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="519dp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description_tv"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:text="@string/detail_error_message"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="651dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/detail_description_label_tv"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:labelFor="@id/description_tv"
    android:text="@string/detail_description_label"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="625dp" />
```

Comment: it's not clear what you want.. can you clarify what you are looking to achieve?

Comment: I want everything to align how it appears in the GUI.  For instance, the ImageView at top, below it, the origin_label_tv with the origin_tv to the right of label, then the also_known_label_tv under the origin_label_tv and so on and so forth.  Does that make sense?

Comment: So you want your layout to look like the image above  , was that the purpose of your question?

Comment: @taraloca so you want your xml file to have the same order of items as that of the GUI?